# Invalid operands 'int' and 'Object' in operator '-'. Godot 3.5

Tags: 2d, godot, gdscript

I'm trying to make an rpg game with turn-based combat. My code needed to have a slight randomness to the damage, and I'm getting this error: Invalid operands 'int' and 'Object' in operator '-'. e stands for enemy in this code

func _on_FIGHT_pressed(): #is connected to a button

```
var damage = RandomNumberGenerator.new()

damage.randomize()

damage.randi_range(pattacks[0][1], pattacks[0][2]) #uses your-only-attacks's min and max damage

ehp -= damage #subtracts your damage from the enemy's hp
```

Before I was using the pseudo-random rand_range bult in method, but then you'd press a button and the same damage would come out the second time you get into a fight.
I am in fact using godot 3.5 release

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that `damage` is a `RandomNumberGenerator`. It says so here:

```
var damage = RandomNumberGenerator.new()
```

You probably want the result of `randi_range` (it returns):

```
ehp -= damage.randi_range(pattacks[0][1], pattacks[0][2])
```